# cakephp url array of named parameters

Tags: url, cakephp-1.3

Let's say I wanna pass a bunch of parameters to a url like:

```
http://localhost/my_app/my_controller/index/param1:1/param2:2/param3:3/param4:4
```

etc...

But my url is built using the `url` method of the [Html Helper](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1448/url) like so:

```
$this->Html->url(array(
    'controller' => 'my_controller', 
    'action' => 'index',
    'param1' => 1, 
    'param2' => 2, 
    'param3' => 3, 
    'param4' => 4
));
```

I tried to build my params into in array like this and pass it to my url like:

```
$my_params = array(
    'param1' => 1, 
    'param2' => 2, 
    'param3' => 3, 
    'param4' => 4
);

$this->Html->url(array(
    'controller' => 'my_controller', 
    'action' => 'index',
    $my_params
));
```

But that doesn't work. Any idea how I can do this please?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you intend to do does not work, because you simply add $my_params to the array when you instead should **merge** the $my_params array with [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

```
$url = array(
    'controller' => 'my_controller',
    'action' => 'index'
);

$my_params = array(
    'param1' => 1,
    'param2' => 2,
    'param3' => 3,
    'param4' => 4
);

$this->Html->url(array_merge($url, $my_params));
```

I hope it helps :)